# Asp.net 4.0 can't get newest focus after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have web application running on .NET 4.0 and I have problem with focus after postback. I think I know where the problem is, but I can't resolve it myself.

JavaScript code that tracks the user's focus and update hidden field.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var focusedElement = null;
    var focusedElementHiddenField = document.getElementById("FocusedElementHiddenField");

    function setFocus(element) {
        focusedElement = element;
        if (focusedElementHiddenField) {
            focusedElementHiddenField.value = element.id; // Przekazanie ID do ukrytego pola
        }

        getHiddenElementValue();
    }

    document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        focusedElement = event.target;
        setFocus(focusedElement);
    });

    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.key === "Enter" || event.key === "Tab") {
            focusedElement = document.activeElement;
            setFocus(focusedElement);
        }
    });

    function getHiddenElementValue() {
        var focusedElementHiddenField = document.getElementById("FocusedElementHiddenField");
        var value = focusedElementHiddenField.value;
        console.log("Hidden Field Value: " + value);
    }
});
```

In ASP.NET, I have hidden field that holds my field id:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="FocusedElementHiddenField" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

`Page_PreRender` method

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string focusedElementId = FocusedElementHiddenField.Value;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(focusedElementId))
            this.Page.SetFocus(focusedElementId);
    }
}
```

`Postback` is hit when user leave text/numeric/dropdown field or by going to another field by pressing key Tab, click or whatever. The `HiddenField ID="FocusedElementHiddenField"` doesn't have actual clicked field id but previous. I think it might be a problem that js code not have time to update `FocusedElementHiddenField` field because postback starts earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest` function.
This function retrieve the instance of the ASP.NET AJAX page request manager and add an event handling function to the page request manager. The 'endRequest' event is triggered after the completion of an asynchronous request (e.g., after a postback has finished).